#  The request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found 

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, jquery

I am using a Form in a LightBox which contains some input element.

```
<form name="imageUploadForm" action="uploadImage.do" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text"  id="id" name="id" style="display: none;" value="">
    <div id="fileUploaderDiv">
         <input type='file' name="file0" id ="file0"  />
    </div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

when i am submitting the form than the form redirect to it's action location. I just want to submit form without redirecting user, so user stay on lightbox without loosing his data.

I have tried jquery ajax call for this

```
var data = new FormData();
var $inputs = $('#imageUploadForm :input');
var values = {};
    $inputs.each(function() {
                values[this.name] = $(this).val();
                data.append(this.name, $(this).val());
            });
$.ajax({
                url: 'uploadImage.do',
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data){
                   alert(data);
                }
            });
```

But getting error at server side in my FileUploader servlet.

```
The request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

can anybody tell me what am i missing in this ?

Comment: Have the submit button trigger a JS event, gather the data and (like elclanrs says) ->AJAX

Comment: This question may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Comment: My Servlet code is http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/java/fileupload.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008049/org-springframework-web-multipart-multipartexception-the-current-request-is-not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simplest form of a form submit using jquery Ajax. I have not tested this but it should work :-)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test form</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sbmt').click(function(){
            var text1 = $('#text1').val();
            var text2 = $('#text2').val();
            /// validation of inputs
            ///then
            $.ajax(
            {
                url :'submit.php',
                type : 'post',
                        data :  {'text1' : text1, 'text2' : text2 },
                success: function(data){
                        alert("form submitted . response is :"+ data);
                    }
            }
            ).fail(function(){alert("Failed!!");});
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myform">
        <input type="text" id="text1" />
        <input type="text" id="text2" />
        <input type="button" id="sbmt"  value="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way, it now looks like you want to pass a file with the form. That's more complex than that. Search for Valums Uploader in google. That's a good uploader if you need ajax file upload

Comment: Impressed by the effort you put forth. :-)

Comment: Thanks man. I love stack exchange and have learned a lot from here. So i try to answer whatever i can, in return :)

Comment: @SugatoSengupta thanks i have tried your solutions in different way but got error at server side.i have edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the default action of submitting the form:

```
$('form[name="imageUploadForm"]').on('submit', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'uploadImage.do',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data){
               alert(data);
            }
     });
});
```

I believe you should set the contentType option to false when using the FormData class, forcing jQuery not to add a Content-Type header, otherwise the boundary string will be missing, and that's probably the reason for your server error.

You must also leave the processData flag set to false, otherwise, jQuery will try to convert your FormData into a string, which will fail.

Comment: I have tried your solution but google chrome throwing a Uncaught TypeError : Illegal Invocation.
b_
f.extend.param
f.extend.ajax
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
f.event.add.h.handle.i