# Create a Form element using javascript and submit it without redirecting/refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using a Form in a LightBox which contains some input element.

```
<form name="imageUploadForm" action="uploadImage.do" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text"  id="id" name="id" style="display: none;" value="">
<div id="fileUploaderDiv">
     <input type='file' name="file0" id ="file0"  />
</div>
<button onclick="javascript:ImageUploader.attachImage();">Upload</button>
</form>
```

can anybody tell me how to copy this form in new one and submit it without redirecting user or knowing him about form submission using javascript or jquery?

Comment: How do you mean 'copy this form'? To submit without redirect/refresh use AJAX.

Comment: Do you want the form to be submitted automatically or only when a button is clicked?

Comment: @amiregelz when button is clicked.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Copy this for means create a new form element and add all filled input element in that form and that new one form will submitted .

Comment: Are you looking for something [like this](http://www.simonerodriguez.com/ajax-form-submit-example/)?

Comment: Why do you want to copy the form and then submit that - why not just submit the existing form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

```
$('#yourbutton_notintheexample_you_provided').click(function(){ 
    var myForm = $('form[name=imageUploadForm]')
    var data = myForm.serialize();
    $.ajax({
       url: myForm.attr('action'),
       type: myForm.attr('method'),
       data: data, 
       success: function(){
           window.alert("write your form handling code here")
        }
    });
});
```

or something along the lines.

In prototype, there was a single convenience method, called Form.request, [read about it here.](http://prototypejs.org/api/form/request)

Comment: I have tried it but it does not work with contentType: 'multipart/form-data',. I need to send multipart . at server side i am getting error in my java code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811232/the-request-was-rejected-because-no-multipart-boundary-was-found#comment15697710_11811232

Answer (score 0):

In order to send data to a server (through submitting a form or otherwise) one can use AJAX.  The user does not need to be informed (but I'd recommend letting the user know somehow).

- [JavaScript tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-javascript.php)
- [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)