# org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request

Tags: spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I am trying to send a multipart request to the server but i am getting the following exception
   HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="imageuploadForm" action="<c:url value="/members/profileimageupload" />" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div style="width:40%; float:left">
                <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                    <div class="fileupload-preview thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"></div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="btn btn-file">
                            <span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span>
                            <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
                            <input id="imageFile" name="imageFile" type="file" />
                        </span>
                        <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="width:40%; float:right" >
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="bar" style="width: 60%;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
       <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Upload</button>
       <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >Close</button>
    </div>
 </div>
```

my ajax call which is sending the request.

```
$(function() {
    //twitter bootstrap script
    $("button#submit").click(function(){
        var $form = $("#imageuploadForm");
        var type = $form.attr('method');
        var url =  $form.attr('action');
        $.ajax({
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: $form.serialize(),

            success: function(msg){
                $("#form-content").modal('hide');
            },

            error: function(){
            }
        });
    });
});
```

my controller which should handle the request

```
@RequestMapping(value="/profileimageupload",method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public void uploadProfileImage(@RequestParam(value="imageFile") final MultipartFile file) throws NumberFormatException, IOException{
    ////
}
```

I had the following web configuration for multipart file

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
    * Supports FileUploads.
    */
    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(500000000);
        return multipartResolver;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 31):

Check whether you have added *CommonsMultipartResolver* in *Spring-Servlet.xml*.

```
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

Then,
  add the enctype to *multipart/form-data* in your form

```
<form id="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Finally in Controller,
   Request > *MultipartHttpServletRequest*

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/profileimageupload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView uploadProfileImage(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {}
```

Dependencies

> 1. commons-fileupload.jar
> 2. commons-io.jar

Answer (score 12):

Try again with "**headers**":

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profileimageupload", headers = "content-type=multipart/*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

and ajax call follow: [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery?lq=1)

I hope this helpful to you!

Comment: I found that the "POST" part is important, it will not work with GET requests.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your tag form is not well formated and everything that is after the

```
'action="<c:url value="/members/profileimageupload" />"'
```

is being ignored.
Try to write like this and see if it works:

```
action="<c:url value='/members/profileimageupload' />"
```