# Android Httpclient [NoSuchMethodError:org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.create]

Tags: java, android, spring

I want upload image from android to spring controller.
I already connected android with spring using rest api call (httpclient)
My code is :

```
final String jsonUserMo = gson.toJson(userMO);
    final StringBuilder contactLists = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); // Timeout
    try {
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        FileBody profileFile = new FileBody(profileImage);
        builder.addPart("uploadImg", profileFile);
        HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userMO", jsonUserMo));
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Constants.ROOTURL+"/media/uploadUserImage");
        post.setEntity(entity);
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        Log.i("Ringee",post.toString());
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        contactLists.append(rd.readLine());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

profile image is file.
and its upload using mutipartentity
But i got error in android

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.create
```

My android dependencies :

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
   compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.4.1') {
      exclude module: 'httpclient'
   }
   compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
}
```

Error :

```
04-22 10:35:16.398  13604-14290/com.ringee.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process: com.ringee.app, PID: 13604
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.create
        at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.buildEntity(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:209)
        at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.build(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:230)
        at com.ringee.app.delegates.MediaDelegates.uploadImageToServer(MediaDelegates.java:51)
        at com.ringee.app.ImageUploadActivity$1$1.doInBackground(ImageUploadActivity.java:85)
        at com.ringee.app.ImageUploadActivity$1$1.doInBackground(ImageUploadActivity.java:82)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please.

Comment: incompatibility between "httpmime:4.4.1" and "httpclient-android:4.3.5"?

Comment: Its correct @RaphhMclee.

Comment: SOF reference:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761347/which-httpmime-version-can-i-use-with-androids-httpclient

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks like you use incompatible jar's for `httpmime` and `httpclient-android`. Try to use version `4.3.6` of `httpmime`

Comment: I am changing dependencies 
 compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5'

Comment: Its fixed but spring controller show error message:the request is not multipart file..

Comment: @nmkkannan refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18292567/1793718 add headers to your request and add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form

Comment: @Jens Thanks for the answer it saved me.Working totally fine.

Comment: Saved my life ❤

Answer (score 2):

I was also doing same like you, then i have just used same library version and it worked,

I don't know how, but below code solved my problem

```
compile( 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
```

Answer (score 1):

**[NoSuchMethodError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html)**

> Thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class
>   (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition
>   of that method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this
>   error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has
>   incompatibly changed.

You should use incompatible  version of both .

```
 compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2') {
      exclude module: 'httpclient'
   }
   compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
```