# No such method for the API in java

Tags: java

I found  a way to copy a file from a source to a destination directory and send it out via the API call. But it's throwing  some errors during the time I'm reading my file in the destination folder for sending it via the API call 
The error message in compiler:

```
File Name :samples_DS.zip
Start to copy file to destinbation folder
Completed
file size :282764
file name :samples_DS.zip
file dir :C://REST API//destination//samples_DS.zip
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Header.addField(Lorg/apache/james/mime4j/parser/Field;)V
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart.addField(FormBodyPart.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart.generateContentDisp(FormBodyPart.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart.<init>(FormBodyPart.java:64)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.addPart(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:116)
    at fileStatus.fileStatus.pass(fileStatus.java:116)
    at fileStatus.fileStatus.main(fileStatus.java:80)
```

In the compiler, I can saw that my java code line 116 and line 80 causing the problem, but I not sure what is the error in that particular line of program, I had add it the required jar file but it's also show me the same error message 
 This is my sample code for line 80

```
try 
{
    statusCheck = new RandomAccessFile(file,"r");
    if(statusCheck != null)
    {
        long filebyte = file.length();
        String filename = file.getName();
        System.out.println("Finish copy");
        System.out.println("\nFile size :"+filebyte);
        System.out.println("\nFile Name :"+filename);
        statusCheck.close();
        Path source = Paths.get(FilePath);
        Path destination = Paths.get("C://REST API//destination");
        System.out.println("Start to copy file to destinbation folder");
        Files.move(source, destination.resolve(source.getFileName()));
        System.out.println("Completed");
        fileStatus fs = new fileStatus();   //line 80
        fs.pass(filebyte,filename);
    }
    break;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("In Copy Process" + e.getMessage());

}
```

This is my sample code for line 116

```
private void pass(long filesize, String filename)
{
    String dir = "C://REST API//destination//";
    String Finalfile = dir.concat(filename);
    System.out.println("file size :" +filesize);
    System.out.println("file name :" +filename);
    System.out.println("file dir :" +Finalfile);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.100:8008/file");  //remote API URL 
    FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File(Finalfile));  // take the file from directory 
    HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()  // build require argument 
                .addPart("file",bin) //line 116
                .build();
    post.addHeader("filename", Finalfile);  
    post.setEntity(reqEntity);  // send via post method 
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try 
    {
        response = client.execute(post);
    } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  // receive response from remote server  
}
```

I have put the indicator in the sample code in order to demonstrate where the error occurs. I have also put some debugging statements in there but all of them are showing the correct parameter such as file name, file size and file path. Please provide me some hints where I have made a mistake.

Comment: could be compatability issue between libraries you are using, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788479/android-httpclient-nosuchmethoderrororg-apache-http-entity-contenttype-create , ignore it that they are talking about android, just check version of libraries

Comment: I change to httpmine 4.3.6 and the problem still the same. Any idea ?